# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate implementation results in UI lag when adding many objects

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a sample app that has a single `NSManagedObject` (let's call the class `CustomObject`) with a single property.

The app has a simple UI consisting of a view controller with a `UICollectionView` using an `NSFetchedResultsController` as the underlying data source.  The `NSFetchedResultsController` is also setup to use the view controller as it's `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` delegate.  Additionally I have toolbar with some buttons to add/remove `CustomObject` items.

One button will result in 10,000 `CustomObject` entities being created.  I'd like to be able to press this button, and once the entities are saved to the disk/ready to be used, the `UICollectionView` should update to reflect the new values.  I am 100% aware that there will be a delay of some kind - saving values like this is not instantaneous - I want the delay to occur on a background thread to prevent the UI from locking up!

Despite me setting things up correctly from what I can tell, I experience UI lag whenever I implement any of the three "important" `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods.  The UI lag duration varies based on the number of `CustomObject`s in the data store already.  For example if I just added the first 10,000, there is only a small amount of lag, less than 1 second.  If I've added 50,000 `CustomObject`s already the lag is much more noticeable and lasts for over 5-10 seconds in some cases.

As I said, the UI lag only shows up when I implement either the `controllerWillChangeContent`, `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath`, or `controllerDidChangeContent` methods.  Even with no actual implementation in the method just the fact that it is in the view controller makes the insertion slow.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?  Is there a way around this?  Here's some code:

CoreDataController.m - responsible for setting up the core data stack

```
//
//  CoreDataController.m
//  CoreDataTestApp
//
//  Created by ZOlbrys on 4/12/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 ZOlbrys. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CoreDataController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CoreDataController()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *persistentStoreURL;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *managedObjectModelURL;

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end

@implementation CoreDataController

+ (CoreDataController *)sharedController {
    static CoreDataController *sharedController;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURL *managedObjectModelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"CoreDataTestApp" ofType:@"momd"]];

        NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSURL *persistentStoreURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[applicationDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataTestApp.sqlite"]];

        sharedController = [[CoreDataController alloc] initWithManagedObjectModelURL:managedObjectModelURL persistentStoreURL:persistentStoreURL];
    });

    return sharedController;
}

- (instancetype)initWithManagedObjectModelURL:(NSURL*)managedObjectModelURL persistentStoreURL:(NSURL*)persistentStoreURL {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.persistentStoreURL = persistentStoreURL;
        self.managedObjectModelURL = managedObjectModelURL;

        [self setupCoreDataStack];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setupCoreDataStack {
    // setup managed object model
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.managedObjectModelURL];

    // setup persistent store coordinator
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];
    [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:self.persistentStoreURL options:nil error:nil];

    // setup MOC
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
}

@end
```

ViewController.m - responsible for, well, view controller stuff!

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  CoreDataTestApp
//
//  Created by ZOlbrys on 4/12/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 ZOlbrys. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
#import "CoreDataController.h"
#import "CustomObject+CoreDataClass.h"

static NSString *const CUSTOM_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER = @"CUSTOM_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER";

@interface ViewController ()<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;

    [self setupFetchedResultsController];
}

- (void)setupFetchedResultsController {
    NSFetchRequest<CustomObject *> *fetchRequest = [CustomObject fetchRequest];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[ [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"identifier" ascending:YES] ];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[CoreDataController sharedController].managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (void)addObjects:(NSUInteger)objectCount {
    NSManagedObjectContext *temporaryContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    temporaryContext.parentContext = [CoreDataController sharedController].managedObjectContext;

    [temporaryContext performBlock:^{
        for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++) {
            CustomObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CustomObject" inManagedObjectContext:temporaryContext];
            object.identifier = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
        }

        NSError *error;
        if (![temporaryContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }

        [[CoreDataController sharedController].managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            NSError *error;
            if (![[CoreDataController sharedController].managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }];
}

- (void)removeObjects:(NSUInteger)objectCount {
    NSManagedObjectContext *temporaryContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    temporaryContext.parentContext = [CoreDataController sharedController].managedObjectContext;

    [temporaryContext performBlock:^{
        NSFetchRequest<CustomObject *> *fetchRequest = [CustomObject fetchRequest];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[ [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"identifier" ascending:YES] ];
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = objectCount;

        NSFetchedResultsController<CustomObject *> *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:temporaryContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

        [fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];

        for (CustomObject *object in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) {
            [temporaryContext deleteObject:object];
        }

        NSError *error;
        if (![temporaryContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }

        [[CoreDataController sharedController].managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            NSError *error;
            if (![[CoreDataController sharedController].managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }];
}

- (IBAction)add10k:(id)sender {
    [self addObjects:10000];
}

- (IBAction)add1:(id)sender {
    [self addObjects:1];
}

- (IBAction)refetchData:(id)sender {
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)remove1:(id)sender {
    [self removeObjects:1];
}

- (IBAction)remove10k:(id)sender {
    [self removeObjects:10000];
}

#pragma mark UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.fetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:section].numberOfObjects;
}

- (nonnull __kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CUSTOM_CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell setDisplayText:@"TODO"];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

//- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
//    // TODO
//}
//
//- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
//    // TODO
//}
//
//- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
//    // TODO
//}

@end
```

Of course, I did some profiling - with `controllerWillChangeContent` uncommented above, I see this:

[image]

Which is not my code - it's internal Apple code...

Here's a github link to a project showing this issue:

[Sample Core Data project](https://github.com/ZOlbrys/CoreDataTestApp)

Answer (score 1):

The lag seems to be related to the chosen Core Data stack:

[**Coordinator**] ← [Main Context] ← [Private Context]

With this architecture, each fetch/save operations on the private context will fall through the main context and then block the UI. A better choice could be to swap the contexts:

[**Coordinator**] ← [Private Context] ← [Main Context]

This time, private context operations will not block the UI.

Another option is to bind both contexts to the coordinator:

[Private Context] → [**Coordinator**] ← [Main Context]

With both solutions, you will need to merge back updated objects to the main context if needed, in order to "see" the changes from the UI.

Comment: The is a good indication of where the issue could be, you also mentioned that the lag appears when you implement the delegates, I wonder if you still keep the delegates empty or you'd  use them to update your collection view, this is a class that given a reference to the fetch result controller and collection view, keeps everything synced. it could help the lag also, https://gist.github.com/arashkashi/89a34aaf0d6ac653607b97d30aa123fc